# How to re-write Vissual Studio func to js func?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

I don't know VS. I have a button which does this function

```
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$btnSave", "", true, "", "", false, false))"
```

How to re-write this for using in js like this

```
function save() {
    do func
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Visual Studio function". Visual Studio is an Integrated Design Environment (IDE). With it, you can write code in several different languages (VB, C#, C++).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the value of the `onclick` attribute and place it into its own named function and then call that function from the `onclick`:

**HTML:**

```
onclick="save()"
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function save() {
  WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
  WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$btnSave", "", true, "", "", false, false));  
}
```